# Collection <__NSCFDictionary: 0x15a2fae0> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am getting this error sometimes in my apps. I printed object and got this:

```
(lldb) po 0x15a2fae0
{
    "0x15d8bcd0.posErrorMarker{id: 4558}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f 00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8baf0.posErrorMarker{id: 4554}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8aad0.negError{id: 4525}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f 00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a3f620.marker{id: 4353}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8bab0.posErrorMarker{id: 4552}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8ad10.posErrorMarker{id: 4526}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8b300:UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height.marker{id: 4567}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f0bf>;
    "0x15d8b3f0.posErrorMarker{id: 4541}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d89a80.negError{id: 4563}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f 00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a3f5f0.marker{id: 4351}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f0bf>;
    "0x15d8baf0.negError{id: 4555}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8b880.negError{id: 4551}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d86b60.posErrorMarker{id: 4546}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8ad50.negError{id: 4529}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a3f4a0.marker{id: 4333}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x1590d210.posErrorMarker{id: 4539}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8a900.posErrorMarker{id: 4516}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8b880.posErrorMarker{id: 4550}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a3f590.marker{id: 4346}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a43eb0.marker{id: 4324}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a43ee0.marker{id: 4326}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8aea0.negError{id: 4535}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8b030.posErrorMarker{id: 4536}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8a900.negError{id: 4517}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a3f560.marker{id: 4343}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d89a00.negError{id: 4561}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f 00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8a8b0.posErrorMarker{id: 4514}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8b840.posErrorMarker{id: 4548}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8b2d0:UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width.marker{id: 4564}" = <00803b44 00000000 000000c0>;
    "0x15d8bc90.posErrorMarker{id: 4556}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f 00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d86b60.negError{id: 4547}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a3f650.marker{id: 4355}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8a8b0.negError{id: 4515}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8b840.negError{id: 4549}" = <00403b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8b3f0.negError{id: 4542}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x1590d210.negError{id: 4540}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a43f10.marker{id: 4329}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8a980.negError{id: 4523}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f 00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d89f00.posErrorMarker{id: 4498}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f 00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a3f530.marker{id: 4340}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8ad50.posErrorMarker{id: 4528}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8ad10.negError{id: 4527}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8a3f0.posErrorMarker{id: 4506}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f 00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8b030.negError{id: 4537}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8a440.negError{id: 4509}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f 00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8b650.negError{id: 4545}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a43f40.marker{id: 4332}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8b650.posErrorMarker{id: 4544}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a43e50.marker{id: 4319}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d8bab0.negError{id: 4553}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15a3f5c0.marker{id: 4349}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f0bf>;
    "0x15d8aea0.posErrorMarker{id: 4534}" = <00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
    "0x15d89f40.posErrorMarker{id: 4500}" = <00803b44 00000000 0000f03f 00007b43 00000000 0000f03f>;
}
```

Is there any help on   this?

Comment: Not very useful output.  Please show the code where this occurs.

Comment: I had a similar problem these days. My issue was related to a for-in with removeObject inside it. Check your application if you are using this kind of iteration and change it to a `for (int i = 0; i < collection.count; i++)`, as an example.

Comment: The topic contains the crucial information which states that the number of elements in the dictionary is mutated (increased or decreased) in the enumeration repeat loop. The po dump is meaningless.

Comment: I am showing a UITableView with custom cell containing image,uilabels. The dictionary I printed above is collection of NSLayoutConstraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you change your collection during iteration. To avoid crash you can copy keys and iterate with them as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686515/collection-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated-uitableview) or use methods suggested by [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-SW2). I think the simplest method is to copy collection before iterate.